# What will be the future of Unity 2d?

Tags: unity, unity-2d

Does anybody know something about the future of `Unity 2D`? Will it be available in coming `Ubuntu` releases?

Comment: Yes, it's going to be the replacement of the Classic Gnome panel desktop in future releases starting in 11.10, for those Pcs that can't handle Unity3D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, [Unity 2D is currently in the Oneiric daily builds](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/05/unity-2d-lands-in-oneiric-daily-build/) and will be the default desktop for lower end machines in future releases.

You can read about it on the Ubuntu wiki (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity2D) and follow the project on Launchpad (https://launchpad.net/unity-2d).

If you follow the wiki instructions you can try it out on Natty too. I've been using it recently, it's not quite as slick as Unity, but my (oldish) machine does run faster.

Comment: Thanx d3vid! I tried it from the ppa and on my older machines it's running quite faster.

Comment: Unity2d doesn't support the nicest keyboard shortcuts yet, etc? Other than that, it's quite nice indeed.